# Can not use AWS Rekognition to detect a video

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rekognition

```
# Detect the contents in a image
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client("rekognition")
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    # Read file from S3 bucket and pass it as bytes
    fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket="rekognition3bucket", Key="test.png")
    file_content = fileObj["Body"].read()

    # Pass bytes data
    response = client.detect_labels(
        Image={"Bytes": file_content}, MinConfidence=50
    )

    # Passing S3 bucket object file reference
    response = client.detect_labels(
        Image={"S3Object": {"Bucket": "rekognition3bucket", "Name": "test.png"}},
        MaxLabels=5,
        MinConfidence=70,
    )

    print(response)
```

The above program can detect the contents in a image. It can show the content labels.
However, it can not detect the contents in a MP4 video.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Rekognition has a few different endpoints depending if you are using it against image or video. The snippet you shared above (specifically `detect_labels`) is for images. You should use `start_label_detection` ([AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_StartLabelDetection.html)) to start the detection and then `get_label_detection` ([AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/APIReference/API_GetLabelDetection.html))to retrieve the results.

A video example might look like:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Start Rekognition Client
    client = boto3.client("rekognition")
    
    # Begin label detection
    start_detection = client.start_label_detection(
        Video={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': "rekognition3bucket",
                'Name': "video.mp4"
            }
        },
        MinConfidence=50
    )

    # Get Labels by JobID
    labels_returned = client.get_label_detection(
        JobId=start_detection['JobId']
    )

    print(labels_returned)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer first. However, after I run your program, I do not see any output labels. I have stored a video in S3 already.

Comment: I get this result : https://i.imgur.com/G1nHs19.png

Comment: I want that this program can detect the contents in a video and show their confidence.

Comment: Looking at your output, the detection is still in progress. It will take time to process.

Comment: Do you mean "JobStatus': 'IN_PROGRESS" ? I undetstand your view now. By the way, where can I see the output lablels ? Or this webpage (i.imgur.com/G1nHs19.png) will automatically show the output labels when the process is finished ?

Comment: @JohnHswson Your program should call [`get_label_detection()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rekognition.html#Rekognition.Client.get_label_detection). The documentation says: "GetLabelDetection returns an array of detected labels". There is an example in the documentation.